# What is the best sound you've created by mistake?

Tags: sound-design, sound-effects

I remember reading somewhere about someone creating a stone door closing when they were packing up for the day and scraped a box along the ground that was covered in salt and I'm sure there's many other examples. So what's the best thing **you've** made by mistake?

Answer (score 1):

one time my ISDN box freaked out on connection, but in an awesome digital kind of way.  I hit record and caught a sound I'd never be able to reproduce otherwise.  For a year or so I used that sound in everything.  :)

Answer (score 1):

i've made some WEIRD stuff by accidentally leaving "noise only" selected when using noise reduction tools like iZotope

Answer (score 0):

Moving a sofa created a wonderful low end growl so I just had to record it.

Answer (score 0):

stepping backwards away from a lecturn and laughing turned in to this amazing phazey sci-fi sound that ended up being a car-start for a futuristic show....

I have a folder full of 'leftovers' that holds all the little gems that might otherwise be indiscriminately culled from a recording session. Things that just sound cool and are hard to categorize.

Comment: i add the term "badass" to the metadata of the REALLY choice stuff i catch.  :)

Comment: ha, nice      .
